# Compute validation loss every n batches with Keras

Tags: python, validation, neural-network, keras, lstm

I am training a recurrent neural network model with a large dataset that takes up to 9 hours/epoch to train. The per batch training loss quickly improves before the end of a single epoch. I would like to know how the validation set loss (or some fraction of it) behaves after every so many batches instead of waiting for the epoch to end (when Keras normally evaluates the model on the validation set). This would give me a better idea of how the model is fitting the data over time. How can I implement this?

Comment: The solution, I've found, is to not use Keras. :)